# How to make the height of a group of a UICollectionView compositional layout equal to the largest UICollectionViewCell in the group?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

As you can see in the image below, I have a UICollectionViewCell that contains an UIImageView with a fixed-height image. Below the UIImageView there is a vertical UIStackView that contains all the labels and sub-stackviews with the title, price e.g.

[image]

The compositional layout section that results in the image's 2-column grid is this:

```
func createSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    // Layout configuration values
    let cellHeight = CGFloat(205.0)
    let sectionTopSpacing = CGFloat(12.0)
    let sectionLeadingSpacing = CGFloat(12.0)
    let sectionTrailingSpacing = CGFloat(12.0)
    let sectionBottomSpacing = CGFloat(12.0)
    let numberOfColumns = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 4 : 2
    let interItemSpacing = CGFloat(8.0)
    let interGroupSpacing = CGFloat(8.0)
    // Item
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .estimated(cellHeight))
    
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
    // Group
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                           heightDimension: .estimated(cellHeight))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                   subitem: item,
                                                   count: numberOfColumns)
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(interItemSpacing)
    
    // Section
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = interGroupSpacing
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: sectionTopSpacing,
                                                    leading: sectionLeadingSpacing,
                                                    bottom: sectionBottomSpacing,
                                                    trailing: sectionTrailingSpacing)
    return section
}
```

I have tried several compression resistance and hugging priority values both for the vertical stack view and it's labels.

Any idea how I could make the items of the same group have the same height according to the group's tallest item would be more than welcome.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Man, i've managed it with custom UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout subclass by adjusting the heights to max in layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath). Also, if you have more than one section you need to adjust y-positions for their items too. For simplicity i will drop this part.

```
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let allAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        return allAttributes?.compactMap { attributes in
            switch attributes.representedElementCategory {
                case .cell:
                    return layoutAttributesForItem(at: attributes.indexPath)

                default:
                    return attributes
            }
        }
    }


    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

        guard let frame = attributes?.frame else {
            return attributes
        }

            if frame.height > maxHeight {
                maxHeight = frame.height
            }
            
            attributes?.frame.size = CGSize(
                width: frame.width,
                height: maxHeight
            )

        return attributes

}


    private var maxHeight = CGFloat.zero
```

Comment: For me this crashes with the error: "UICollectionView (<UICollectionView 0x12901e400>) is stuck in its update/layout loop. This can happen for many reasons, including self-sizing views whose preferred attributes are not returning a consistent size. To debug this issue, check the Console app for logs in the "UICollectionViewRecursion" category."

Comment: The crash seems to only be for iOS 15

Comment: Even on iOS 14 though this is not the desired answer. This resizes all cells to the be same as the largest of the entire collection view. Instead the height of the two cells *per group* should be the same size.